# Cual es el nombre de esto?

Tags: base-de-datos

nosotros lo llamamos dlr, si por estas iniciales lo conocen, que significan esas iniciales?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: DLR nunca lo ví con esas siglas, en español lo conozco como DER, Diagrama de entidad relación.

Comment: Es cierto lo que dice @PatricioMoracho, lo que nos muestras en tu imagen es un DER (Diagrama de Entidad Relación), puede que DLR lo condundas con UML que es lenguaje unificado de modelado, lo digo por la "L". Saludos

Comment: @PatricioMoracho tal como me lo enseñaron a mí el DER es a más alto nivel; esto parece describir la estructura de tablas con lo cual sería el *Diagrama (o Modelo) Relacional*. Por ejemplo, en un DER *Especialidades_Medicos* sería una relación, no una entidad.

Comment: Esos son Diagramas de base de datos, esos son Modelos Relacionales de base de datos que se diferencian de los modelos entidad-relacion. El MER (Modelo Entidad-Relacion) y el MR (Modelo relacional) Son dos cosas muy distintas, y no se puede hablar de uno u otro. Sino que estos se complementan. El MER se usa para un relevamiento en una etapa mas temprana pudiendo luego a partir de este obtenerse el MER, el cual luego se puede refinar.

Comment: Los DLR (Data Log Records) en base de datos hacen referencia a un formato de logs que usan para protegerse de fallas del sistema y transacciones erroneas.

Comment: Yo el único DLR que conozco [es este](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Language_Runtime). Para mi eso es un DER o Modelo Relacional.

Comment: @SJuan, depende.. hay varios "modelos" de DER, creo que el que apunta a bases de datos es el [IDEF1X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEF1X)

Answer (score 1):

DLR es un Diagrama lógico-relacional.